# How to delete block on hook_uninstall?

Tags: 8, blocks, hooks

I have a custom module, mymodule, that will create custom blocks, `block_test` and `block_test2` on `mymodule_install()`.

When the module is uninstalled, I want to remove any blocks created by `mymodule`. How would I delete the block generated by a module being uninstalled?

drush command (local dev):

```
drush pmu mymodule -yv
```

**mymodule.uninstall()**

```
function mymodule_uninstall() {
  // Delete Blocks generated by module.

  /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface $block_storage */
  $block_storage = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('block');
  /** @var \Drupal\block\Entity\Block[] $blocks */
  $blocks = $block_storage->loadMultiple();
  foreach ($blocks as $block) {
    // I am stuck here. 
  }
}
```

Comment: What kind of blocks? content blocks? You could try using enforced config dependencies, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2404447

Comment: @Berdir the boxes are of `basic block` types that come with Core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, then the best thing would be to follow the enforced config dependencies part above, if you create the content blocks with a fixed uuid then you can just put the block config entities in your config/install folder, with the config dependencies as explained there and it should be uninstalled automatically.

At least the config entities, if you want to delete the block_content entities too then load them by UUID with `$block_content = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->loadEntityByUuid('block_content', 'YOUR_UUID'); $block_content->delete()`